# Why JNDI InitialContext can work fine in jsp but not in a class?

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, jndi

I'm working with Database connection using JNDI. I'm sure the deployment is fine. Because when I test it in the JSP below, it works fine.

```
</head> 
<body> 
<% 
try { 
    Context initCtx = new InitialContext();
    Context envCtx = (Context) initCtx.lookup("java:comp/env");
    DataSource ds = (DataSource)envCtx.lookup("jdbc/airlineticket");
    Connection conn = ds.getConnection();
out.println(conn); 
conn.close(); 
} catch (Exception e) { 
e.printStackTrace(); 
}
%> 
</body> 
</html>
```

[success connection picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O8qNX.png)

But when I use ConnectionFactory class, an error occurs: **ConnectionFactory cannot be resolved.** I just put the connection code in the ConnectionFactory class, why this happened?
ConnectionFactory class:

```
package com.db;

import javax.naming.*;
import java.sql.*;
import org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource;

public class ConnectionFactory {
    private ConnectionFactory() {};
public static Connection getConnection()
    {
        try {
            Context initCtx = new InitialContext();
            Context envCtx = (Context) initCtx.lookup("java:comp/env");
            DataSource ds = (DataSource)envCtx.lookup("jdbc/airlineticket");
            return ds.getConnection();
        }
        catch (NamingException e)
        {
            System.out.print("connection failed");
            return null;
        }
        catch(SQLException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

test JSP:

```
  <%@ page language="java" import="java.util.*,com.db.ConnectionFactory" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%> 
</head> 
    <body>     
    <% 
    try {       
    Connection conn = ConnectionFactory.getConnection(); 
    out.println(conn); 
    conn.close(); 
    } catch (Exception e) { 
    e.printStackTrace(); 
    }
    %> 
    </body> 
    </html>
```

web.xml(/WEB-INF/web.xml):

```
<resource-ref>
  <res-ref-name>jdbc/airlineticket</res-ref-name>
  <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
  <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
```

context.xml(/META-INF/context.xml):

```
<Context>
    <Resource name="jdbc/airlineticket" 
        auth="Container" 
        type="javax.sql.DataSource"
        username="Manager" 
        password="123456"
        driverClassName="org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver"
        url="jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/airlineticket"
        maxActive="50"
        masIdle="20"> </Resource>
</Context>
```

Comment: Have you imported your class in the JSP?

Comment: I import the  ConnectionFactory class in the JSP :<%@ page language="java" import="java.util.*,com.db.ConnectionFactory " pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

Comment: And your `ConnectionFactory` class really has the package name `com.db`? The package name is left out in your example.

Comment: this is the ConnectionFactory class:
package com.db;

import javax.naming.*;
import java.sql.*;
import org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource;

public class ConnectionFactory {
 private ConnectionFactory() {};

Comment: It works in a container because the container sets the initial factory.

Answer (score 0):

- Are you able to build the application fine?
- Make sure you have deployed the class file properly.

JSP will be recompiled automatically... whereas the java files, we have to build and deploy everytime, until unless if you are using JRebel....

If you have done this already, I wish to see your complete logs...